# what exactly Cucumber test, it is about service interface or function? and do it need to connect DB to get real data?

Tags: java, cucumber

I am just the beginner of java Cucumber BDD testing, I want to know in what case we need to use Cucumber to test?

Does it relate to service interface or the whole function(maybe combines serval interface)?

Does it need to retrieve the real data from Database?

please answer me, thanks.

I have built up the technical part, configured the maven dependencies and already integrate Cucumber with SpringBoot.

I just don't know which part Cucumber could deal with. it's not relate to coding, it's about the concept.

none

Comment: Welcome to SO. Never used it but as far as I know : It is a tool based on Behavior Driven Development (BDD) framework which is used to write acceptance tests for the web application. 
You might like to go through the [following](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/cucumber-bdd-tool-selenium-tutorial-30/), here they have mentioned few case scenarios related to Cucumber.
Kindly go through the documentation provided by the [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/docs) also.

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber is a tool best used to exercise a piece of functionality that is important to the business. It creates additional overhead in comparison to other test tools to allow the thing that describes and instigates the test to be written in the language of business rather than in the language of code.

Because of this extra overhead Cucumber is best used for big things like

- buying a product
- registering to use an application
- making a complaint
  ...

rather than little things like

- ensuring my password has a symbol in it
- ensuring that my complaint has an email address with it
- ensuring that have checked box A and not checked box C

In particular Cucumber is not a tool for doing any kind of exhaustive testing. So if you had an online form with 15 fields on it, Cucumber would be good tool to show that you can use the form to do something, and a good tool to use to show that an error appears when you input bad data, but a bad tool to deal with all the possible combinations of bad data you could enter (you should use a unit test tool for this).